# Saving/Exporting ggplot2 data, not the plot itself

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to save or export the ggplot data used for plotting? I do not mean the image itself but the information r stores in the global environment.

For example:

```
Data <- data.frame(
    X = sample(1:10),
    Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))

p <- ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Y, y=X)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

What I want is to export "p" as csv or txt. Is this possible? I tried "write.table(p)" but I get the error: "cannot coerce class "c("gg", "ggplot")" to a data.frame"

Comment: Can you export `Data` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes I can but I am still wondering if it is possible to export the plot information somehow.

Comment: What exactly would you want to export? `p` is a `ggplot` object, not a data frame. If you want the data that was interpreted into geoms, use `p$data`, but this is likely the same as `Data`. If you want the dataframe that has positions and other information used in assembling geoms, use `ggplot_build(p)$data`

Comment: Maybe just dput(p)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Create some data and plot
library(tidyverse)
p <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), ncol = 2, 
                     dimnames = list(1:10, c("x", "y")))) %>%
  mutate(group = as.factor(round((mean(y) - y)^2))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()

# you can't write it as txt or csv:
glimpse(p)

#List of 9
# $ data       :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ x    : num [1:10] -0.612 0.541 1.038 0.435 -0.317 ...
#  ..$ y    : num [1:10] 0.2065 0.9322 0.0485 -0.3972 -0.048 ...
#  ..$ group: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 3 1
# $ layers     :List of 1

# but you can write it as Rds
write_rds(p, "./myplot.Rds")
# and read and plot afterwards:
read_rds("./myplot.Rds")
```

[image: random plot]